# Why does the implementation of std::any use a function pointer + function op codes, instead of a pointer to a virtual table + virtual calls?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, std

Both the [GCC](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/any) and [LLVM](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/any) implementations of `std::any` store a function pointer in the `any` object and call that function with an `Op`/`Action` argument to perform different operations. Here is an example of that function from LLVM:

```
static void* __handle(_Action __act, any const * __this,
                          any * __other, type_info const * __info,
                          void const* __fallback_info)
    {
        switch (__act)
        {
        case _Action::_Destroy:
          __destroy(const_cast<any &>(*__this));
          return nullptr;
        case _Action::_Copy:
          __copy(*__this, *__other);
          return nullptr;
        case _Action::_Move:
          __move(const_cast<any &>(*__this), *__other);
          return nullptr;
        case _Action::_Get:
            return __get(const_cast<any &>(*__this), __info, __fallback_info);
        case _Action::_TypeInfo:
          return __type_info();
        }
        __libcpp_unreachable();
    }
```

**Note:** This is just one `__handle` function but there there are two such functions in each `any` implementation: one for small objects (Small buffer optimization) allocated within `any` and one for big objects allocated on the heap. Which one is used depends on the value of the function pointer stored in the `any` object.

The ability to choose one of two implementations at run-time and call a specific method from a pre-defined list of methods is essentially a manual implementation of a virtual table. I'm wondering why it was implemented this way. Wouldn't it have been easier to simply store a pointer to a virtual type?

I couldn't find any information about the reasons for this implementation. Thinking about it, I guess using a virtual class is sub-optimal in two ways:

- It needs an object instance and managing a singleton, whereas in reality a vtable (without an instance) is enough.
- Calling a function on `any` would involve two indirections: first through the pointer stored in `any` to get the vtable, then through the pointer stored in the vtable. I'm not sure if the performance of this is any different to the `switch`-based approach above.

Are these the reasons for using an implementation based on `switch`-ing op-codes? Is there any other major advantage of the current implementation? Do you know of a link to general information about this technique?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. GCC and LLVM use a vtable/vptr for `virtual`, but I don't see how you'd rewrite this `switch` using `virtual`. Yes, this looks like a table of functions, but vtables make sense because of vptr's to select the right vtable. Here, there's only one table, and the `switch` selects a table entry within the single table.

Comment: I would suppose this implementation is faster, because it only uses one indirection while vtables require at least two indirections.

Comment: This not really similar to a vtable. For a vtable, you would need to dynamically allocate the object containing the actions and then call the action, but here you need no allocation since the implementation uses static methods on templated structure. All the dispatch is known at compile time, so you don't need to let anything be deduced at runtime. This is compile-time dispatch vs. runtime dispatch, and implementations will prefer the first one most of the time.

Comment: @MSalters, @Holt: I updated the question with a Note under the code.

Each `any` implementation has 2 possible `__handle` functions. Which one is used is actually chosen at run-time, since the `any` object is not templated and uses type erasure instead.

Comment: Generally you can't find any information on why something was implemented in a library that way or another but the best way to find out is to try to reach out to the person who did it and ask them. You can also implement `any` yourself and benchmark it. It isn't really that hard.

Comment: MSVC also has a similar implementation with the following comments all over it: _"Hand-rolled vtable <...>"_ Looks like they all agree that it is faster to reimplement vtable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a typical use case of a `std::any`: You pass it around in your code, move it dozens of times, store it in a data structure and fetch it again later. In particular, you'll likely *return it from functions* a lot.

As it is now, the pointer to the single "do everything" function is stored right next to the data in the `any`. Given that it's a fairly small type (16 bytes on GCC x86-64), `any` fits into a pair of registers. Now, if you return an `any` from a function, the pointer to the "do everything" function of the `any` is already in a register or on the stack! You can just jump directly to it without having to fetch anything from memory. Most likely, you didn't even have to touch memory at all: You know what type is in the `any` at the point you construct it, so the function pointer value is just a constant that's loaded into the appropriate register. Later, you use the value of that register as your jump target. This means there's no chance for misprediction of the jump because *there is nothing to predict*, the value is right there for the CPU to consume.

In other words: The reason that you get the jump target for free with this implementation is that the CPU must have already touched the `any` in some way to obtain it in the first place, meaning that it already knows the jump target and can jump to it with no additional delay.

That means there really is no indirection to speak of with the current implementation if the `any` is already "hot", which it will be most of the time, especially if it's used as a return value.

On the other hand, if you use a table of function pointers somewhere in a read-only section (and let the `any` instance point to that instead), you'll have to go to memory (or cache) every single time you want to move or access it. The size of an `any` is still 16 bytes in this case but fetching values from memory is much, much slower than accessing a value in a register, especially if it's not in a cache. In a lot of cases, moving an `any` is as simple as copying its 16 bytes from one location to another, followed by zeroing out the original instance. This is pretty much free on any modern CPU. However, if you go the pointer table route, you'll have to fetch from memory every time, wait for the reads to complete, and then do the indirect call. Now consider that you'll often have to do a sequence of calls on the `any` (i.e. move, then destruct) and this will quickly add up. The problem is that you don't just get the address of the function you want to jump to for free every time you touch the `any`, the CPU has to fetch it explicitly. Indirect jumps to a value read from memory are quite expensive since the CPU can only retire the jump operation once the entire memory operation has finished. That doesn't just include fetching a value (which is potentially quite fast because of caches) but also address generation, store forwarding buffer lookup, TLB lookup, access validation, and potentially even page table walks. So even if the jump address is computed quickly, the jump won't retire for quite a long while. In general, "indirect-jump-to-address-from-memory" operations are among the worst things that can happen to a CPU's pipeline.

TL;DR: As it is now, returning an `any` doesn't stall the CPU's pipeline (the jump target is already available in a register so the jump can retire pretty much immediately). With a table-based solution, returning an `any` will stall the pipeline *twice*: Once to fetch the address of the move function, then another time to fetch the destructor. This delays retirement of the jump quite a bit since it'll have to wait not only for the memory value but also for the TLB and access permission checks.

Code memory accesses, on the other hand, aren't affected by this since the code is kept in microcode form anyway (in the µOp cache). Fetching and executing a few conditional branches in that switch statement is therefore quite fast (and even more so when the branch predictor gets things right, which it almost always does).

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to use virtual functions directly in `any`. Instead, I'm wondering why `any` doesn't store a pointer to a virtual class, as opposed to a pointer to a function. In that approach, `any` will remain 16 bytes and moving/copying the `any` will remain exactly as trivial and cheap as today. There would be no additional stalls to the CPU pipeline. The only time you would need to access the virtual functions is when you need to access the stored value. Even in the current implementation of `any` operations on the stored value happen indirectly through the handler pointer.

Comment: @DimitarAsenov Yes, that is exactly what I described: ```any``` either stores a pointer to a single "do-everything-by-opcode" function (first case) or a pointer to a table of function pointers (second case). It's 16 bytes in both cases. However, moving and deleting an ```any``` requires a function call: You might need to move (and certainly will have to delete) the contained type. That means there are two function calls every time you return an ```any```. (Remember that ```any``` implementations do small buffer optimization, therefore moves also need the indirect call.)

Comment: Let's take deletion. With the function approach, you need to jump to the `handler` function (somewhere in memory) and then dispatch to the `deleter` function (somewhere in memory) based on the opcode. With the virtual class, you would need to load the vtable (from somewhere in memory) and then jump to the `deleter` function (somewhere in memory). So there are 2 memory accesses in both approaches and the first one is always unconditional. Is that right? Could you explain why the memory accesses in the first case are quicker? Is it because of inlining the functions that the op-codes point to?

Comment: In the first case (single function pointer), you have obtained the ```any``` from *somewhere*. That means the CPU has already touched the ```any``` and therefore knows the jump target up-front - no pipeline stall so far. Next, it'll do a bunch of comparisons in the switch, which are *direct branches* and therefore easily predictable (based on branch history). Still zero pipeline stalls for the entire operation! And yes, the functions in each switch case will be inlined. For the "table" case, the CPU will always have to fetch the function address from memory first, causing a stall.

Comment: You say "the CPU has already touched the `any` and therefore knows the jump target up-front`". This is indeed true, but knowing the jump target address, and having the memory at that address be in a hot cache are not the same thing. A stall is still possible if the jump target is not hot. In the virtual-class based approach, the CPU would also have the address of the vtable in a register. So is the assumption here that the memory of the handler function is much more likely to be hot, than the memory of the vtable? If yes, why would that be?

Comment: The problem really isn't whether particular pieces of memory are hot or not (they all are), the problem is with indirect jumps to a value fetched from memory. Indirect jumps that depend on memory accesses are the single worst thing that can happen to a CPU pipeline. If you can instead arrange for the address to be in a register (or in the CPU's store buffer), you simply don't have that "memory-to-indirect-jump" dependency that will make your pipeline explode. Putting the function pointer right into the ```any``` makes sure the CPU (almost) never has to do that "memory-to-indirect-jump" thing.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to reflect your last comment. In the current answer you say that "you will have to go to memory every single time ...", but in the comment above you say that the issue isn't "whether particular pieces of memory are hot or not". If a piece of memory is hot, meaning in the cache, then you wouldn't have to go to memory. Assuming you don't have to go to memory, why would a load (from cached memory) + a single indirect jump be slower compared to a direct jump (to cached code) + a second jump based on opcode?

Comment: Thanks. The new explanation is cleaner and I accepted the answer. I'm wondering, if this is a general case, do you know why the standard vtable mechanism isn't implemented in the same manner (with a function pointer)? Is there any situation where vtables are better, or is C++ just stuck with the status quo because of ABI compatibility?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243720/discussion-between-jonathan-s-and-dimitar-asenov).